# Cordova/Phonegap app is not showing the changes I've made in the jade files

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, pug

I'm using grunt to show my changes that I've made in sublime text. But whenever i use cordova prepare, cordova build android, and cordova run android it only shows the previous version of the app on the emulator and my android device.

Comment: are you updating the files in `/platform/android/www` or `/www`?

Comment: No the /www folder doesn't have a jade file @DawsonLoudon

Comment: where are you making changes that aren't showing up in the build?

Comment: src/app/ folder @DawsonLoudon

Comment: @DawsonLoudon should I add the jade files to _/www_ folder?

Comment: When `cordova prepare / build / run` are called, cordova copies all files from `/www` into `/platform/android/www` and the `index.html` in that path is the default view loaded, unless you have changed those settings.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon how can i check if the settings have been changed?

Comment: You would have had to change them yourself in `config.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my changes were not navigating to the cordova folder because I didn't run *grunt build-ios* in the command line.